# connect h5fy weight have an error

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

[the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhbph.png)

[the second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBvFS.png)

the errors:

```
  File "merge.py", line 48, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=1, validation_split=0.2)
  File "/home/ngxin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1117, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/ngxin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1034, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model target')
  File "/home/ngxin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 112, in standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (31000, 1)
```

thank you

Comment: You should include your code, not a picture of it if you want people to help.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look the code,The model recognition rate that can be saved at the beginning is good, but the second stage of the connection model (where the same two models are connected) is very bad, and I think it should be my save model and the process of connecting Problem, but there is no error in the console, thanks!

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = faces_load_data()#the data is an numpy array
model = Sequential()the procedure is not being given
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3,
                   border_mode='valid',
                   input_shape=(48, 48,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3,3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(7))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

gen = ImageDataGenerator()
gen.fit(X_train)
train_generator =gen.flow(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=32,shuffle=False)
test_generator = gen.flow(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=32,shuffle=False)
train = model.predict_generator(train_generator, 31000)
test= model.predict_generator(test_generator, 3589)
with h5py.File("model_common.h5") as h:
    h.create_dataset("train", data=train)
    h.create_dataset("test", data=test)
    h.create_dataset("label", data=y_train)#sava mode ,there should hava a problem

for filename in ["model_common.h5","model_common.h5"]:
   with h5py.File(filename, 'r') as h:
        X_train.append(np.array(h['train'])) 
        X_test.append(np.array(h['test']))
        y_train = np.array(h['label'])
X_train = np.concatenate(X_train, axis=1)
X_test = np.concatenate(X_test, axis=1)
X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
input_tensor = Input(X_train.shape[1:])
x = input_tensor
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model = Model(input_tensor, x)
model.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=1,     validation_split=0.2)
```